# Get logged in user's email while using firebase database in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm using firebase auth and cloud database on this react project.
I have a user collection that has names of users.

What I want to do is show name of the logged in user in Home Component.

My App.js codes is checking user is valid and if yes --> go to home, if not --> show login page. Inside that I'm trying to fetch user email value using `{this.state.user.email}` calling it email and match database in user collection using  `.where("email "==","email")` in firebase.

This is my App.js code

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
      userlists: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
    this.getUser();
    this.showUserInfo();
  }

  authListener() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log("App:login user info", user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
      }
      // console.log("App:user.email",user.email)
    });
  }

  showUserInfo() {
    fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .where("email", "==", email)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const userlists = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = doc.data();
          userlists.push(data);
        });
        this.setState({ userlists: userlists });
      });
  }

  getUser = () => {
    const email = this.state.user.email;
    showUserInfo(email);
    console.log("App: email:", email);
  };

  render() {
    // console.log("user",user)

    return (
      <Router>
        <AppShell>
          <div>
            {this.state.user ? (
              <>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/"
                  render={props => (
                    <Home {...props} loggedInUser={this.state.user} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/profile"
                  render={props => (
                    <Profile {...props} loggedInUser={this.state.user} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop} />{" "}
              </>
            ) : (
              <Login />
            )}
          </div>
        </AppShell>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I am only trying to render logged in user's information to Home Component I the email value keeps saying it is undefined. What is the problem? I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.where("email", "==", email)`? Otherwise you're just comparing two strings.

Comment: You are mixing a few concepts, which makes it hard to understand and debug the code. 1) you should not be mixing hooks and a class like this. It's perfectly fine to use either, but using both is confusing in this case :)

Comment: and 2) you are mixing async/await with the usage of an actual promise in showUserInfo. Both issues are not related to the error you are seeing (which is, as pointed out by Clarity, a fautly `where` clause).

Comment: "it used to work fine until I added ShowUserInfo and getUser function that fetch fireabase." So what is the error now? What is the problem?

Comment: I fixed("email", "==", email) part that @Clarity mentioned and

Comment: I removed hooks and changed it all to class components @philipp pointed out

Comment: The problem is I want to put an value of email inside showUserInfo(); so only the data of logged in user's data can show up. but right showUserInfo(); cannot read the value of {user.email } and gives me undefined

Comment: it's `this.state.user.email`

Comment: thank you @Clarity and as you said, if updated it to ```.where("email", "==", this.state.user.email)``` and do you know which value i have to render to Home component pass it on? cuz i'm trying console.log but can't see the result of showUserInfo()

Comment: The user is set in `authListener` not in `showUsers`.